# Definition and properties of support

Tags: data-mining, statistics

From [Xiong, Hui, Shashi Shekhar, Pang-Ning Tan, and Vipin Kumar. “TAPER: A Two-Step Approach for All-Strong-Pairs Correlation Query in Large Databases.” Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on 18, no. 4 (2006): 493–508.](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/papers/taper.pdf)
:

> Support measures the fraction of transactions that contain a
>   particular subset of items. The notions of support and correlation may
>   not necessarily agree with each other. This is because item pairs with
>   high support may be poorly correlated while those that are highly
>   correlated may have very low support. For instance,
>   suppose we have an item pair {A, B}, where supp(A)
>   = supp(B) = 0.8 and supp(A, B) = 0.64. Both items are uncorrelated because supp(A, B) = supp(A)supp(B). In contrast, an item pair {A, B}
>   with supp(A) = supp(B) = supp(A, B) = 0.001 is perfectly correlated
>   despite its low support.

I don't quite follow the example about support. Could anyone give a proof of $supp(A)supp(B) = supp(A, B) \iff A \text{ and } B \text{ are uncorrelated}$ ? I don't even quite understand what $supp(A, B)$ means. Is there a book or paper on support vs correlation?

Comment: 1) Please give a robust reference (Name, title, year, DOI). 2) How do the authors of that article define support? What properties can you find in the literature?

Comment: Edited. Author's definition already quoted. The term "support" is too common and not very search-friendly in this case, especially for someone not in the field, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the definition is clear: support is exactly "the fraction of transactions that contain a particular subset of items." This is a data-mining term, not a statistics term.

$supp(A)$ is the fraction of transactions that contain item $A$. $supp(B)$ is the fraction of transactions that contain item $B$. $supp(A,B)$ is the fraction of transactions that contain the subset $\{A,B\}$.

Now, your question really seems to be more about how the authors expound on this, which does seem to be a little unclear. As a statistic, support can basically mean, "What is the probability that this subset of items is contained in a random transaction?" That is, you can consider that $supp(A)=\mathbf{P}(A)$.

Then you can see that 
$$supp(A)supp(B) = supp(A, B) \iff A \text{ and } B \text{ are uncorrelated}$$
comes from the definition of [statistical independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)),
$$\mathbf{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbf{P}(A)\mathbf{P}(B) \iff A \perp B.$$

Comment: Could you please recommend some materials for further reading?

Comment: @qed https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning and the book http://www.dataminingbook.info/pmwiki.php